# Navigate to parent from child and execute functions in parent Angular2

Tags: angular

I have parent with some data, which should be get from database when navigating back to parent from one of child components. This children is displayed with router-outlet.

We start that user get's navigated to parent from login page, with no child visible. I have list in parent, which is get from the database when navigate to page

```
constructor(private todoService: TodoService) {
   this.todoService.getData()
     .subscribe(data => this.data)
}
```

This works good. This list is displayed, and when user chooses one of these items, user get's navigated to one child, where he update this with new value and then navigated back to parent. Like:

```
update(todo) {
  this.service.updateData(todo)
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.router.navigate(['parent'])
   });
}
```

**The problem:** When user gets navigate back to the parent, the parent list do not update, I think is because parent is always there? When I refresh list is ok, so update in child works.

How can I tell the parent component to execute `this.todoService.getData()` which is in constructor so that I have the new version of data from the database, so I not need to refresh page.

Comment: your parent constructor never execute second time until it is destroyed so my suggestion is that use an eventemmiter to inform parent to update let me know if you need example ?

Comment: can you share your template as well with parent child ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that your child is behind a router-outlet. You could use a shared service, but I think it might be overkill here, since you just want to tell the parent to execute function. So use a Subject instead that tells parent to execute the functions you want.

BTW, move your function in parent to `OnInit` instead:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.todoService.getData()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
    });
}
```

When that is done, declare a Subject in your parent

```ts
public static updateList: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
```

inside parent constructor, listen to child action and subscribe to that:

```ts
ParentComponent.updateList.subscribe(res => {
   this.todoService.getData()
    .subscribe(data => {
       this.data = data;
    });
});
```

and in your child:

```ts
update(todo) {
  this.service.updateData(todo)
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      // add this!
      ParentComponent.updateList.next(true);
      this.router.navigate(['parent'])
   });
}
```